# DJI drone location - Mobile SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I am currently trying to implement a waypoint using DJI's mobile SDK.

However, it is difficult to obtain the position of the drones when connected without simulation.

What should I do?

Comment: Please do specify the problem with code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you outdoors with a good GPS signal?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine your real question but if the aircraft has a clear view of the sky then it will attach to a number of GPS satellites and report location through the call as shown below.  If you don't have a clear view to the sky (technically southern exposure) then the GPS will not be able to establish a connection to the GPS satellites and will not report location.  Unlike your cellphone (which can use GPS, cell site and WIFI to locate itself) the aircrafts only have GPS.

```
                Application.getAircraftInstance().getFlightController().setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {

                    }
                });
```