# getAircraftLocation() - getting a "NaN" (Not a Number) for Lat/Lng in Android

Tags: android, location, dji-sdk

Good afternoon guys,

After succeeded to establish a connection ( in the **MainActivity.java** ) with the drone ( getting its Model Name and enabling the Open Button ), I open a new Activity ( **LocationActivity.java** ) where I have to display the Aircraft ( **Model : M210** ) location in a Toast message.

What I'm getting in the message : Lat / Lng = **NaN / NaN**

```
private FlightController mFlightController;
private double mDroneLocationLat;
private double mDroneLocationLng;
```

In the **onCreate()** method, I created a Broadcast receiver :

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(FPVDemoApplication.FLAG_CONNECTION_CHANGE);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

**FPVDemoApplication** is a java file where the DJI constructor has written some codes + created a Broadcast sender. You can find it on Github.

Then :

```
protected BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        onProductConnectionChange();
    }
};

private void onProductConnectionChange()
{
    initFlightController();
}
```

In the **initFlightController()** method, I'm using the following codes to get the Aircraft location : **getFlightController()** and **getAircraftLocation()**.

```
BaseProduct product = FPVDemoApplication.getProductInstance();

if (product != null && product.isConnected()) {
    if (product instanceof Aircraft) {
        mFlightController = ((Aircraft) product).getFlightController();
    }
}

        // Getting Aircraft
        // ================
        if (mFlightController != null) {
            mFlightController.setStateCallback(
                    new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUpdate(FlightControllerState
                                                     djiFlightControllerCurrentState) {
                            mDroneLocationLat = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLatitude();
                            mDroneLocationLng = djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getAircraftLocation().getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
```

-

**The questions are :**

1. Did I forget to use some methods to have the aircraft location ?
2. Which permissions do I need to access the information about the Aircraft location in the **Manifest.xml** or another java file ?
3. As my aircraft is in a office room, **do I have to go outside to get its location** ( according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318441/dji-drone-location-mobile-sdk/51353902#51353902) )?

Here is the structure tree :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : It was very stupid >.< ! I forgot to attach the GPS antenna on the drone and go outside to have a better signal level. The **getAircraftLocation()** was correct but if you got **LEVEL_0** with this method ( **djiFlightControllerCurrentState.getGPSSignalLevel()** ) you won't get the drone location